# Python on nginx using fcgiwrap - upstream closed prematurely FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream

Tags: python, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I am trying to get a hello world python script to run on my nginx web server. I am getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error when I try and load up the URI: **http://sub.dom.com/py-bin/hello.py**

This is the error that is in my nginx error log.

```
2013/04/27 13:54:14 [error] 14158#0: *1 upstream closed prematurely FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream,
client: w.x.y.z, server: sub.dom.com, request: "GET /py-bin/hello.py HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "sub.dom.com"
```

Location of **py-bin**: /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/py-bin

Location of **public_html**: /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/public_html

Location of **hello.py**: /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/py-bin/hello.py (chmod 777)

Location of **fastcgi_params**: /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

Contents of **nginx config**

```
server {
    server_name sub.dom.com;
    access_log /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/logs/error.log;
    root /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.html index.php /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ ^/py-bin/.*\.py$ {
        gzip off;
        root /home/cluber/www/sub.dom.com;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.py;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Contents of **fastcgi_params**

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Location of socks:

```
ls /var/run | grep sock
fcgiwrap.socket
php5-fpm.sock
```

Contents of **hello.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "Hello world"
```

Note that PHP works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the response code ("`HTTP/1.0 200 OK`") to the top of the output from your `hello.py` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print ""
print "Hello world"
```